# How do I redirect all requests with URLs beginning with "www" to a naked domain?

Tags: python, redirect, heroku, dns, flask

I have been successful in adding Heroku custom domains for my app. I'd like to know how to capture requests that begin with `www` and redirect them to the naked domain. For example, I have the following custom domains mapped to my Heroku app:

```
www.myapp.com
myapp.com
```

Requests for `http://myapp.com` and `http://www.myapp.com` are both successful, but the `www` stays on.

#### Objective

I want all requests for `http://www.myapp.com` to be redirected to `http://myapp.com`. This should also work for other paths, like `http://www.myapp.com/some/foo/bar/path` redirects to `http://myapp.com/some/foo/bar/path`. I want something like this: http://www.stef.io and see how the `www.` is gone from the address bar.

The instructions I've found on Google so far are about editing my `.htaccess` file, but I'm running on Heroku with a Python app on the Flask framework.

Comment: While admittedly www-less domains are more aesthetically pleasing, Heroku discourages the use of apex domains when possible. Read the resolution section of this issue for more details https://status.heroku.com/incident/245

Answer (score 8):

The recommended solution for this is DNS level redirection (see [heroku help](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords#subdomain_redirection)).

Alternatively, you could register a `before_request` function:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

@app.before_request
def redirect_www():
    """Redirect www requests to non-www."""
    urlparts = urlparse(request.url)
    if urlparts.netloc == 'www.stef.io':
        urlparts_list = list(urlparts)
        urlparts_list[1] = 'stef.io'
        return redirect(urlunparse(urlparts_list), code=301)
```

This will redirect all www requests to non-www using a "HTTP 301 Moved Permanently" response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Flask, but you could set up a route that matches /^www./ and then redirect it to the url without the "www".

You may want to check http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#custom-converters or http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#host-matching