# How do I redirect to the www. version of my Flask site on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I've got a Python Flask app running on Heroku (Cedar stack) with two custom domains (one with and one without the www subdomain). I'd like to redirect all incoming requests to the www. version of the resource requested (the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350141/how-do-i-redirect-all-requests-with-urls-beginning-with-www-to-a-naked-domain)). I think I need some WSGI middleware for this but I can't find a good example.

How do I do this?

Comment: To clarify, you have `example1.com`, `example2.com` and `www.example2.com`. You want all requests to `example1.com` and `example2.com` to be redirected to `www.example2.com`. Is that correct?

Comment: just example.com and www.example.com with example.com/<path> redirecting to www.example.com/<path>

Comment: Couldn't you just do this with DNS? Why do you want to do that at the application layer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An easier solution than to create a separate Heroku app would be a `before_request` function.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

@app.before_request
def redirect_nonwww():
    """Redirect non-www requests to www."""
    urlparts = urlparse(request.url)
    if urlparts.netloc == 'example.com':
        urlparts_list = list(urlparts)
        urlparts_list[1] = 'www.example.com'
        return redirect(urlunparse(urlparts_list), code=301)
```

This will redirect all non-www requests to www using a "HTTP 301 Moved Permanently" response.

Comment: I did some something similar, but instead of replacing an index, you can use `urlparts = urlparts._replace(netloc='www.example.com')` and `urlunparse(urlparts)`

Comment: for python3: replace `from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse` with
 `from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse`

Comment: The best would be to organise the redirect natively with your dns provider with an A ALIAS for example

Comment: @aflaisler DNS doesn't change the hostname sent by the client in the HTTP request. That's what this is for.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Heroku Docs, you've got the right idea about using the www subdomain (eg www.foo.com) vs apex domain (eg foo.com). Their suggestion for dealing with this is to use a DNS layer redirect:

To quote:

> Subdomain redirection
>
> Subdomain redirection results in a [301 permanent redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) to the
>   specified subdomain for all requests to the apex domain so all current
>   and future requests are properly routed and the full www hostname is
>   displayed in the user’s location field.
>
> Almost all DNS providers offer domain redirection services - sometimes
>   also called domain forwarding. [DNSimple](http://dnsimple.com/) provides a convenient URL
>   redirect seen here redirecting from the heroku-sslendpoint.com apex
>   domain to the www.heroku-sslendpoint.com subdomain.

Source:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-apex-domains-dns-arecords#subdomain_redirection

Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem with DNS based solutions is that they don't preserve the path. So this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to add a function to listen on [`request_started`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.request_started), and do the appropriate redirection.

> This signal is sent before any request processing started but when the
>   request context was set up. Because the request context is already
>   bound, the subscriber can access the request with the standard global
>   proxies such as request.

Comment: looks promising. not sure how i would issue a response from there yet, but looking into it.

Comment: Initially I thought you'd need to mess with werkzeug but its not as straight forward as the flask hooks into it. If the signals don't work, you can always try your hand at some [werkzeug middleware](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/middlewares/).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a second Heroku app, assigning the non-www hostname to that one and using a catch all Flask route to redirect to the www version keeping the path intact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], subdomain="www")
@app.route('/<string:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST'], subdomain="www")
def www(path=''):
    return redirect(url_for('app.index')+path)
```