# Domain routing in Flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I wanted to redirect users from test1.domain.com to test2.domain.com. I tried 'host_matching' in url_map along with 'host' in url_rule. It doesn't seem to work, shows 404 error.For example, on visiting 'localhost.com:5000' it should go to 'test.localhost.com:5000'.

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.host_matching = True

@app.route("/")
def hello1():
    #return "Hello @ example1!"
    return redirect(url_for('hello2'))

@app.route("/test/", host="test.localhost.com:5000")
def hello2():
    return "Hello @ test!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Is it possible? Has anyone tried?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Would the answers to this question help in your situation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766134/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-www-version-of-my-flask-site-on-heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in your code is redirecting a request from `localhost.com` to `test.localhost.com`. You would need to respond with an http redirect to requests for `localhost.com` if you wanted this to happen. [You also need to specify the host for all routes when you set host_matching to true](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#host-matching).

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.host_matching = True

@app.route("/", host="localhost.com:5000")
def hello1():
    return redirect(url_for("hello2")) # for permanent redirect you can do redirect(url_for("hello2"), 301)

@app.route("/", host="test.localhost.com:5000")
def hello2():
    return "Hello @ test!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Bear in mind that you will also need to map `localhost.com` and `test.localhost.com` to 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file.

Comment: Yeah..I tried redirect. Updated my question. You solution also isn't working. Did you try? subdomain routing works properly but not this one.

Comment: Just tested it and updated it, it's working now. You also need to specify the full host including port numbers. And the redirect needs to include the schema `http://` in order to function.

Comment: Its will just redirect to "http://test.localhost.com:5000", it is normal right?. We are just redirecting to another site.

Comment: Ok. I replaced 'return redirect("http://test.localhost.com:5000")' to redirect(url_for('hello2')) it worked fine. One thing I missed is 'host' in first route . Thanks.

Comment: In your question you say "on visiting 'localhost.com:5000' it should go to 'test.localhost.com:5000'." To achieve this you send the browser a redirect. It then makes another request. How else were you expecting it to work?

Comment: I dont want to hard code in redirect function. url_for should take care of it. Its working now. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I didnt expected to write 'host' in all route. I'm building multi-tenancy app, I want to redirect user to 'register.domain.com' for registration when they visit any un-registered domain ex: 'test.domain.com', 'py.domain.com'. If you have any idea, please let me know. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Flask is not designed for this. You'll need to use Nginx / Apache to provide a catchall that redirects to your registration application.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need; but I can't get it working. [What am I missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28544180/656912)